# Get the last 4 characters of output from standard out

Tags: linux, bash, shell, character

I have a script that is running and uses

```
lspci -s 0a.00.1
```

This returns

```
0a.00.1 usb controller some text device 4dc9
```

I want to get those last 4 characters inline such that

```
lspci -s 0a.00.1 | some command to give me the last 4 characters.
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

How about `tail`, with the `-c` switch. For example, to get the last 4 characters of "hello":

```
echo "hello" | tail -c 5
ello
```

Note that I used 5 (4+1) because a newline character is added by `echo`. As suggested by Brad Koch below, use `echo -n` to prevent the newline character from being added.

Comment: `echo -n` would prevent that newline byte from being added.

Comment: In my bash, you can't have a space between the "-c" and "5".  It had to be "tail -c5", not "tail -c 5".

Answer (score 18):

Do you really want the last four characters? It looks like you want the last "word" on the line:

```
awk '{ print $NF }'
```

This will work if the ID is 3 characters, or 5, as well.

Answer (score 6):

Using `sed`:

```
lspci -s 0a.00.1 | sed 's/^.*\(.\{4\}\)$/\1/'
```

Output:

```
4dc9
```

Comment: You might improve that with: `sed -n '$s/.*\(....\)$/\1/p'`; this only prints the last line of output, and 4 dots are simpler than the the 6 characters used to describe it with the `.\{4\}` notation.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, say if the string is stored in the variable foo.

```
foo=`lspci -s 0a.00.1` # the foo value should be "0a.00.1 usb controller some text device 4dc9"
echo ${foo:(-4)}  # which should output 4dc9
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use

```
echo 0a.00.1 usb controller some text device 4dc9 | rev | cut -b1-4 | rev
4dc9
```

Comment: While that works, it seems like a lot of processes involved in the effort.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: But very fast. I often find `rev|cut|rev` the fastest of all possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If the real request is to copy the last space-separated string regardless of its length, then the best solution seems to be using `... | awk '{print $NF}'` as given by @Johnsyweb. But if this is indeed about copying a fixed number of characters from the end of a string, then there is a bash-specific solution without the need to invoke any further subprocess by piping:

```
$ test="1234567890"; echo "${test: -4}"
7890
$
```

Please note that the space between colon and minus character is essential, as without it the full string will be delivered:

```
$ test="1234567890"; echo "${test:-4}"
1234567890
$
```

Comment: Apologies, I just noticed that this solution is in fact identical with Mingjiang Shi's suggestion only ommiting the brackets around the offset.

Comment: You can delete this answer if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `grep`:

```
lspci -s 0a.00.1 | grep -o ....$
```

This will print last 4 characters of every line.

However if you'd like to have last 4 characters of the whole output, use `tail -c4` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to approach this is to use `<<<` notation:

```
tail -c 5 <<< '0a.00.1 usb controller some text device 4dc9'
```

Comment: This only works efficiently when the source content comes in a variable or in a fixed string. In that case it does indeed avoid an unnecessary pipe including two processes instead of one, by writing the variable or fixed string directly into stdin of tail. However, the OP wants to get the last four characters from the output of a command, which using your construct would have to be

Comment: (..) would have to be "tail -c 5 <<< "$(lspci -s 0a.00.1)", which is still equal to a pipe, just harder to read, (Sorry, got cut off from editing my previous comment due to unknown time limit of 5 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using named variables, develop the practice of using the positional parameters, like this:

```
set -- $( lspci -s 0a.00.1 );   # then the bash string usage:
echo ${1:(-4)}                  # has the advantage of allowing N PP's to be set, eg:

set -- $(ls *.txt)
echo $4                         # prints the 4th txt file.
```