# Convert PuTTY Raw SSH output to plain text

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, putty

I have a 240MB logfile from a PuTTY session.  This was mistakenly logged in the "SSH packets and raw data" format instead of "All session output".  If I open the file in a text editor then I can see that the data I require (the plain text).

The problem is extracting that from the raw data.

For example:

```
Incoming raw data at 2016-01-06 15:47:42
  00000000  e8 fd c2 d2 88 a9 39 b9 2a 77 2a 7b 4a 60 fc 21  ......9.*w*{J`.!
  00000010  1d f5 fc d4 b1 58 1f 4d 68 a4 ef 83 03 39 59 b7  .....X.Mh....9Y.
  00000020  41 be 36 7b b5 3c 10 fa 65 27 77 30 77 97 02 39  A.6{.<..e'w0w..9
  00000030  46 4c 28 da 5c c6 2c 1e ae 33 db e1 a8 09 ea 4a  FL(.\.,..3.....J
  00000040  06 94 c6 eb 38 8e d3 d3 33 13 78 08 7c 5f 41 56  ....8...3.x.|_AV
  00000050  f1 13 9e e1                                      ....
Incoming packet #0x31, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 20 64 69 73 61 62 6c 69 6e  ....... disablin
  00000010  67 20 61 20 72 75 6e 6e 69 6e 67 20 77 61 74 63  g a running watc
  00000020  68 64 6f 67 2e 2e 0d 0a                          hdog....
Incoming raw data at 2016-01-06 15:47:42
  00000000  dc 96 f3 54 f8 a8 5c 83 80 7b a8 07 da 79 95 50  ...T..\..{...y.P
  00000010  3f 19 2f 0c f0 03 a1 01 a3 33 2f 97 75 9d 47 15  ?./......3/.u.G.
  00000020  b9 95 df c6 66 e0 50 32 88 1e db 5b 73 1b 7b ad  ....f.P2...[s.{.
```

I think what I need to do is read only the sections of the file labelled "Incoming packet".  Then I can read the ascii character codes and convert to readable text (this will recover the tabs, linefeeds and carriage returns).

I'm not familiar with awk or sed, but I know a bit of grep.  How can I go about firstly extracting the sections (of variable size) that I need to translate from ASCII codes to text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^Incoming packet/,/^Incoming raw data/{//!p}
```

This will print lines between the matches `Incoming packet` and `Incoming raw`. Process this output further to get your desired output.

Print only ASCII characters (print last 17 characters) from the matching line:

```
sed -n '/Incoming packet/,/Incoming raw data/{//!{s/^.*\(.\{17\}\)/\1/;p}}'
```

Ref:[1](https://nixtricks.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/sed-delete-the-lines-lying-in-between-two-patterns/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219964/bash-get-the-last-4-characters-of-output-from-standard-out-inline)

Comment: "Teach a man to fish" by giving him a stick and pointing to the ocean ...?

Comment: My opinion is something is better than nothing if it motivate them to start learning. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately there are also "Outgoing packet" & "Outgoing raw data".  They aren't in a consistent order.  The matching would have to be between /^Incoming packet/ and either /^Outgoing/ or /^Incoming raw data/
I thought i could do this with:

sed -n '/^Incoming packet/,/^Incoming raw data/\|/^Outgoing/}{//!p}'

But no....

Comment: Correct syntax is : `/^Incoming raw data\|^Outgoing/`