# Get the last two letters of each line in a file using script shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a .txt file with *20* lines, and would love to get the last two letters of each line. it equals **AA** in every line then print *Good*. if not, print *Bad*.

```
line11111111111111111 AA
line22222222222222222 AA
line33333333333333333 AA
..................... 
line20202020202020202 AA
```

This is **GOOD**.

===========================

```
line11111111111111111 AB
line22222222222222222 AC
line33333333333333333 WD
..................... 
line20202020202020202 ZZ
```

This is **BAD**.

Did this but needs improvement : `sed 's/^.*\(.\{2\}\)/\1/'`

Comment: Please show your attempts

Comment: my attempt is using sed: sed 's/^.*\(.\{2\}\)/\1/' but doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing last x characters of a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19858600/608639), [A command to print only last 3 characters of a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163481), [Is there a cleaner way of getting the last N characters of every line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24427009/608639), [Get the last 4 characters of output from standard out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9219964/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single command `awk`:

```
awk 'substr($0, length()-1) != "AA"{exit 1}' file && echo "GOOD" || echo "BAD"
```

`substr($0, length()-1)` will extract last 2 characters of every line. awk command will exit with `1` if we don't fine `AA` in any line.

Comment: can improve like this : awk ' $NF !="AA" {exit 1}' ad.txt && echo "good" || echo "bad"

Comment: @yoga: I initially thought about that but that is only possible when last 2 characters have a whitespace before that. OP's example shows that but it is not mentioned in question.

Comment: Either that or jww is around and didn't like the question so all answers were downvoted regardless of technical correctness.

Comment: as per the example of the OP, this will work and tested it as well. BTW i did not down vote.

Answer (score 2):

based on your file layout

```
$ awk '$NF!="AA"{f=1; exit} END{print (f?"BAD":"GOOD")}' file
```

note that you don't have to check the rest after the first non "AA" token.

Comment: This appears to be the most efficient of the lot.

Answer (score 0):

This script shoud work with awk. The name of the txt file for me is **.test** you can change it with your file name.

```sh
if [ "$(awk '{ print $2 }' .test | uniq)" = "AA" ]; then 
  echo "This is GOOD"; 
else echo "This is BAD";
fi
```

**How it works:**
First, awk is used to get the second column by `awk '{ print $2 }'` and using `uniq` command we are taking unique entries from each line. If all the lines are AA uniq makes it only 1 line. At last we check whether this last product is only "AA" (1 line string with 2 As) or not.

Comment: Prints "This is bad" every time.

Comment: do you populate .test file?

Comment: yes i did. i think it's the awk command, i cant see where it extracts the last two characters of each line ?

Comment: awk splits lines by whitespace by default so using `{ print $2 }` it extracts second column. Try `cat .test | awk '{ print $2 }'` and see

Comment: Also *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`*) `awk '{print $2}' .test | ...` instead of `cat .test | awk '{print $2}' .test | ...`  (any time you use `cat`, if you are not actually *concatenating* files, there is a good chance it is a UUOc)

Comment: thanks david, I don’t know awk enough. I will update the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `grep` invert-match to identify lines not ending with "AA":

```
if egrep -q -v AA$ input.txt; then echo "bad"; else echo "good";fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution with `grep` and `wc`:

```
if [ "`grep -v 'AA$' your-file-here | wc -l`" == "0" ] ; then echo 'GOOD' ; else echo 'BAD' ; fi
```

The `grep` command checks for all lines not ending with `AA` and `wc` counts how many lines.

Comment: I'm not your downvote, but I suspect your downvote is due to using `==` (a string comparison, which should properly be `=` for strings) instead of using `-eq` for a numeric comparison. Additionally, don't use *backticks* for *command substitution*, instead use `$(...)`. Your intent appears to have been `if [ $(grep -v 'AA$' file | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo good; else echo bad; fi` which while valid spawns no less that 4-subshells.